# How do I call a Stored Proc in a Select Statement (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Trying to run code below, it doesn't work, how do I fix it?

```
SELECT Number_ID, EXEC dbo.UselessStoredProc @inputNum=Number_ID as ModifiedNumber
FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[Numbers]
```

Stored proc looks like this and works if called separately:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UselessStoredProc @inputNum int
AS
SELECT 'lol my number is: ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), @inputNum)
GO

--TEST
EXEC dbo.UselessStoredProc @inputNum=2;
```

I do need to run the stored proc, not get the value in line. Code is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By converting your procedure to a table valued function and using `cross apply()`:

```
create function NotAProc (@inputNum int) returns table as 
return 
select ModifiedNumber = 'lol my number is: ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), @inputNum);
go

select Number_ID, tvf.ModifiedNumber
from Numbers
  cross apply NotAProc(Number_ID) as tvf
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HCJZQ54253

returns:

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| Number_ID |   ModifiedNumber    |
+-----------+---------------------+
|         0 | lol my number is: 0 |
|         1 | lol my number is: 1 |
|         2 | lol my number is: 2 |
|         3 | lol my number is: 3 |
|         4 | lol my number is: 4 |
|         5 | lol my number is: 5 |
|         6 | lol my number is: 6 |
|         7 | lol my number is: 7 |
|         8 | lol my number is: 8 |
|         9 | lol my number is: 9 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

Reference:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: What if I need my stored proc to call a stored proc, e.g. execute dynamic SQL to get the primary key column of some table, e.g. `'SELECT @Data_Table_Key = COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), ''IsPrimaryKey'') = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @Data_Table_Name + ''''` This is my reason for not using a function.

Comment: I guess I don't understand `table valued function` - can I call stored procs from it? Still, no, right @SqlZim?

Comment: @VSO If you are executing dynamic sql in a procedure and you want to loop through a bunch of values and execute the procedure for each value then that's exactly what you would need to do. Use a `while` loop, or `cursor` to execute the stored procedure for each value. -- Please post relevant examples of code next time